# How to solve problem related to BigQueryError "reason": "invalid", "location": "test", "debugInfo": "", "message": "no such field."

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Someone worked before with streaming data into (google) BigQuery using Google Cloud Functions (`insert_rows_from_dataframe()`)?

My problem is it seems like sometimes the table schema is not updated immediately and when you try to load some data into table immediately after creation of a new field in the schema it returns an error:

> BigQueryError: [{"reason": "invalid", "location": "test", "debugInfo": "", "message": "no such field."}]"

However, if I try to load again after few seconds it all works fine, so my question if someone knows the maximum period of time in seconds for this updating (from BigQuery side) and if is possible somehow to avoid this situation?

Comment: What is the size of your dataframe (number of row)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere how this is related to my problem?

Comment: The `insert_rows_from_dataframe()` is an extension of `insert_rows()` which stream data into bigquery. The streaming rate is limited to 1M rows per second. If you have a high number of row, you maybe reach this limit.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I know what you are talking about, but problem is not in this

Comment: Can you share more about you code? When are you defining your schema, when are you creating your table, when are you loading the data?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, this error is related to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#metadata-errors-for-streaming-inserts), so after creating a new field in schema is not always updated immediately, in this case appear problem that I described above, from bigquery side exit sometime delay (new table is not updated (this can take few minutes) and exist just somewhere in cache), when you try to load data after table update it raise this error that "no such field.", that means table is not yet ready to load data in this new field

Answer (score 1):

Because the API operation on BigQuery side is not atomic, you can't avoid this case.

You can only mitigate the impact of this behavior and perform a sleep, a retries, or set a Try-catch to replay the `insert_rows_from_dataframe()` several times (not infinite, in case of real problem, but 5 times for example) until it pass.

Nothing is magic, if the consistency is not managed on a side, the other side has to handle it!

Comment: Thank you,I already had this idea, but problem is that for e.g. how you will know that 5 times will help? I mean, I not found out yet in documentation about this delay maximum delay in sec, do you found somewhere about this? Before implementation this logic I need to have an ~ estimation in sec otherwise this is not useful and you don't know what can happen.

Comment: 5 times is a reasonable number of tries. But indeed, there is no commitment on the delay, it's in best effort on Google side. Maybe a day, when the conditions won't be good, it could take minutes or hours. The aim is not to have an infinite loop, but to have a good balance.

Comment: my point is that the aim is not to have a good balance but an working and stable (code) execution, without any error and control over any situation that may arise! But in any case thank you for getting involved, I still think that Google in future will fix this somehow or exist other solution.

Comment: I'm sorry. Having a stable solution between 2 part with no commitment on 1 side is absolutely impossible. I can only advice for mitigating the issue, but there is no 100% working solution. Open a feature request, maybe they could provide you a maximum delay for schema update. I can't do more! Courage!